# If the Goa'uld exile you on an unknown planet with a Stargate, can you escape?

Tags: stargate, stargate-sg1

**Situation:** The Goa'uld exile you (an SG team member) off-world on a planet with a Stargate.

**Problem:** You don't know the Point of Origin but you do, of course know the first six glyphs for Earth.

- **How many tries do you get in order to dial Earth?**

  - **Do you need to try all 39 of the other glyphs on the Stargate if you don't know the Point of Origin?**

For reference, [here](http://rdanderson.com/stargate/glyphs/glyphs.htm!) are some pictures of gate addresses.

[image: symbol wheel]

Comment: yep assume the six glyphs are in correct order, assume you're an sg team member and you memorized the correct six glyphs order for earth.

Comment: Why the VTCs as 'off topic' (scientific solution/explanation) ?  This is clearly being asked within the context of a specific work of sci-fi which is permitted.

Comment: Your edit introduces a whole new question ("**What does an SG team do if they can't access the Earth gate?**"). That should be posted as a new question, not an edit.

Comment: @Richard thanks will post as new question.

Comment: @tls - If you click the edit button, you'll be able to see the original text that you added.

Comment: I can, but only because I have Macgyver on my team.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

IIRC the point of orgin is a unique symbol, so you just use the unique symbol on the DHD for the point of origin.

if you're​ talking a math question, then you have 6 glyphs that you know the order of, leaving 33 symbols to try so 33 attempts at dialing.

Comment: it's what i also remember, what i can't recall is whether the order of first six glyphs remain constant. say dialing abydos from earth, you will also use the same first six when dialing abydos from chulak.

Comment: technically they would have to its an address after all

Comment: The glyphs for Earth always remain in the same order.

Answer (score 13):

This precise situation occurred in the *SG-1* episode ["Prisoners"](https://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Prisoners). In that particular case the team are exiled to a world with no DHD. The lack of a ready power-source and any way to dial the gate is the reason they can't simply leave until they work out how to generate some energy and dial the gate by turning the ring by hand.

To answer your specific questions:

- You can dial the gate **as many times as you like**. Theoretically you'd only need 33 attempts to *find* the unique point-of-origin but in reality, the SG-1 team would immediately recognise the unique symbol. **It only takes them one *go*.**

Comment: It happened right back in the movie, the very first canon Stargate adventure! Indeed, arguably it happens every single time they go to a new world.

Comment: @Richard - thanks, it puts the original movie in a new light for me. Daniel could have gotten them home but i suppose his desire to explore led him to deceive Jack.

Comment: @tls: No -- in the original movie Daniel initially did not *know* the six symbols for Earth. (The glyphs he deciphered back on Earth were those of Abydos.)

Comment: @DevSolar Right! Thanks! i forgot the order of events. Kowalski found the tablet in the cave with Daniel, Shauri,and Jack.Kowalski then asked Daniel to take a look at it. http://www.stargate-sg1-solutions.com/wiki/Stargate:_The_Movie_Transcript and Daniel says "It's worn out. I can't make it work without the seventh symbol." still a strange statement to say to Jack.

Comment: @tls: Note that your question was working from false assumptions. You mentioned the Goa'uld and the SG teams -- making the answers refer to the TV series canon. In the series, there is only *one* unique symbol on each stargate, with the remaining glyphs being "global" among all stargates. In the movie, *all* glyphs on the two stargates are unique -- just figuring out the one glyph that differed wouldn't have worked in the movie. (Pet peeve: If 39 glyphs are "global", using star constellations as-seen-from-earth, an eight symbol to dial somewhere in the Pegasus galaxy doesn't make *any* sense.)

Comment: to anyone. i'd like to ask another hypothetical question. Slightly different from the first but related. It's too long for comments. Should i just make another question even tho its related to my first question. Or can i just edit and add to the original question

Comment: @tls - Better to ask a new question if it's a new question. If it's strongly related, just add it as an edit.

Comment: @DevSolar Not entirely true.  The Earth point-of-origin was on the Icarus planet's gate in Stargate Universe, and there was at least one instance in SG-1 where they zoomed in on the gate to show that glyph on an off-world gate as well

Comment: @Izkata: But how can six star constellations from our galaxy, *as seen from earth*, plus the symbol for earth itself, plus *another* star constellation from our galaxy, reference a point in *another* galaxy? Answer: They can, because we needed it for the story. ;-) (The whole concept, as depicted in the movie, also implies that stargate technology is *earth*-based, i.e. invented by Ra, which *also* doesn't make sense in the TV series' universe.) Don't argue, or I drag in the black hole thingummy to show how they played fast and lose with logic / physics whenever it served the plot. ;-)

Comment: @DevSolar: within the movie, a lot of things make no sense. E.g. why you have to tell the Stargate where you are coming from. Or, well, the entire concept of using *constellations* to navigate in space. After all, a constellation is *not* a point in space like Daniel has drawn on the board. It consists of stars which appear close to each other only when looking at them from earth. The distance between them might be even much bigger than their smallest distance from earth. So the TV series treating the symbols more like phone numbers makes much more sense.

Comment: @DevSolar good eye! after viewing stargate movie again - it does show different glyphs on earth gate and abydos gate (from the glyphs that i can see). It is true the "one unique glyph approach" would not work. But Daniel still has 33 other combinations he can try. It still seems Daniel is misleading Jack when Daniel claims "It's worn out. I can't make it work without the seventh symbol."

Comment: Also, when you've only ever seen two gates, it's pretty much impossible to even know that some of the symbols are common and one is unique.

Comment: Hate to jump in here late, but the constellations were spatial coordinates selected by the Ancients while on Earth. This was explained in a later episode, maybe an Atlantis one. The Pegasus galaxy gates had constellations as seen from Lantea.